# How to use com_users model class in my custom component in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have created a custom component in `Joomla 2.5`. In this component I want to fetch all the user 's are available in `com_users`.For this I want you to know, How can i use `com_users` **model class** in to my component. Any one have suggestion's to how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where you want use the model you can simply ask Joomla! to load it for you.

In a `JController` class or sub-class you can call `getModel` passing in the model name and the components prefix...

e.g.

```
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_users/models/');
$model = $this->getModel($name = 'User', $prefix = 'UsersModel');
```

*It may be necessary to add the path of the external model you want to load using `JModel::addIncludePath()` as show above.*

Or if you're sure of the model name and the class prefix you could use `JModel`'s `getInstance()` to create the desired model object... e.g.

```
$model = JModel::getInstance('User', 'UsersModel');
```

Alternatively in a view you could:

```
$myModel = $this->getModel('myOtherModel');
$this->setModel($myModel);
```

*N.B. In the first line we're passing our desired models name, normally you call `getModel` without any params to load the default model for your components view controller. In the second line, as we're only passing the model to `setModel()` it won't make it the default model the view uses.*

When we want to use our model objects later on we can specify which we want to use like this:

```
$item = $this->get('Item');
$otherItem = $this->get('Item', 'myOtherModel' );
```

The first line uses the view's default model (because we have specified one in the optional parameter). The second line uses the `getItem()` from `myOtherModel`.

That's all works because `JView` (in *`libraries/joomla/application/view.php`*) has these methods:

```
/**
 * Method to get the model object
 *
 * @param   string  $name  The name of the model (optional)
 *
 * @return  mixed  JModel object
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function getModel($name = null)
{
    if ($name === null)
    {
        $name = $this->_defaultModel;
    }
    return $this->_models[strtolower($name)];
}

/**
 * Method to add a model to the view.  We support a multiple model single
 * view system by which models are referenced by classname.  A caveat to the
 * classname referencing is that any classname prepended by JModel will be
 * referenced by the name without JModel, eg. JModelCategory is just
 * Category.
 *
 * @param   JModel   &$model   The model to add to the view.
 * @param   boolean  $default  Is this the default model?
 *
 * @return  object   The added model.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function setModel(&$model, $default = false)
{
    $name = strtolower($model->getName());
    $this->_models[$name] = &$model;

    if ($default)
    {
        $this->_defaultModel = $name;
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: So it can also be apply to use other component's model class?

Comment: See my updated answer for a few alternative ways to load your specific model.

Comment: I put this line in my controller `$model = $this->getModel($name = 'User', $prefix = 'UsersModel');` and echo it but it doesn't return any thing at all.

Comment: Depending on where in your code you want to load the model you may have to give `JModel` the path to look in... e.g. t may be necessary to add the path of the external model you want to load using `JModel::addIncludePath()`

Comment: Nothing happen even after adding my model class path.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? You are running with debugging turned on right?

Comment: Nothing it's return a blank page while echo it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22359/discussion-between-cppl-and-tornado)

Comment: Ya it was my fault i had put a wrong method to get the component file,and i have put `JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_users/models/');` this and it's start working, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
if(!class_exists('UsersModelUser')) require(JPATH_ROOT.DS.'administrator'.DS.'components'.DS.'com_users'.DS.'models'.DS.'user.php');
```

You can add correct path the model from admin side or front end.

The VM2.x component is using like this way.

Or you need only some details about user you can use.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: I know that by include that file i can use all function of it,But i don't want to use `require`.Is there any Joomla method or plugin ,it would be helpful.

Comment: there is only require or include functions for including core files , if you want to include libraries then u can use jimport()